# How to check if NSDate chosen by user occured some years ago?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

In my application I need to check if user turned 18. I provide UIDatePickerView for him and he selects his birthday date. I store it in the NSDate field.
How to check if 18 years has passed already since his birthday?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:birthDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0] year]
```

or as [Jonathan Grynspan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265530/jonathan-grynspan) pointed out, this would be better:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
int years = [[gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:birthDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0] year];
[gregorian release];
```

and now with ARC it can be (overly) brief:

```
int years = [[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:birthDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0] year];
```

Comment: Careful--`currentCalendar` is not guaranteed to be Gregorian/solar. It is lunar in many countries. You'll want to specifically use the Gregorian calendar for age calculations.

Comment: Perfect. Of course there will be no correct solution without checking this.

Answer (score -2):

It should be done with something like that:

```
    NSTimeInterval interval = [birthday timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (interval > 18*365*24*60*60) {
    NSLog(@"You're more than 18");
}
```

Comment: This does not count bisextil years and everithing

Comment: Yes ... I wanted to do it this way but quickly recognize the same issue.